# Build successful, but has errors

Tags: android, android-studio

On Clicking Run in the android studio the 'Messages windows' showing following error.

[image]

don't have any clue...whats causing this?

Comment: Exclude annotations library in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the information for the libraries in your `build.gradle` file. They are residing in Google's Maven repository. You should check for the following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Or in Android Studio 3, replace

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

with `google()`.